# typo3 tt_news item visibility and "read more" issue

Tags: typo3, tt-news

I have a typo3 site with 3 pages each listing latest `news`, `events`, `vacancies` using tt_news.

The item listings for 3 pages display the clickable title, summary and a clickable "read more" link for each item.

One of the 3 pages (e.g `events`) seems to have a problem though because the item title and "read more" texts are not clickable.

I've found that this happens because these specific items are not viewable from the public site (anonymous users). The item's full view is only viewable via the backend.

My problem is that I don't know how and why this happens. Any ideas on where should I look at next?

Answer (score 0):

This might happen if the detail page for that type of news isn't visible to all users, as TYPO3 normally won't display links to pages it knows they're invisible to the user.

Also, make sure the correct singlePID (page for detail view) is assigned. This could also be set in the settings for the category the concerned elements belong to.

Comment: How do I find whether the detail page isn't visible?

Note that I've compared all options (General, Plugin [General Settings, Template, Category Settings, Other Settings], Appearance, Access, Extended) of the host pages that work (`news`, `vacancies`) to the one that does not work (`events`) and I do not find any difference at all apart from the fact that they fetch tt_news records from pages.

Comment: An hidden page has a stop-sign-icon in the pagetree, in the page settings there's a ticked checkbox for that, and the page is not accessible from the web when you're not logged into BE (use another browser or restart after logout).

Comment: Another strategy is that you start afresh by replicating one of the working pages and changing the parameters to events ...

Comment: btw if you're building a new site you might want to look at http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/news/ which is the successor to tt_news